# Three very similar functions operating on XML files

Tags: python, xml

I have 3 functions which are annoyingly similar, but I can't figure out a way to refactor them without making the code unreadable.

The three functions deal with xml files (`.resx`), the first function reads all files in a directory and "collects" all strings inside a `data.value` tag, adds them to a set and returns that set, for example:

```
<data name="AccessibilityTitleResource1.Text" xml:space="preserve">
<value>Pages Accessibility</value>
```

The second function reads these same files, and swaps the values read previously with a translation which is inside a dict called `definicoes` (`definicoes[english] = translation`), with the previous example, then saves the file. So from our previous example `definicoes["Pages Accessibility"] = "Acessibilidade de Páginas"`. The xml file would become:

```
<data name="AccessibilityTitleResource1.Text" xml:space="preserve">
<value>Acessibilidade de Páginas</value>
```

The third function simply checks if the xml file is fully translatable, so it checks all the values `<value>` tags inside the `<data>` ones against the ones in the dict, if there is any value not present on the dict it returns False.

Here are the three functions:

```
def ler_todos(caminho) -> set:
    definicoes = set()
    for file in os.listdir(caminho):
        if file.endswith(".ascx.resx") or file.endswith(".aspx.resx"):
            tree = ET.parse(caminho + file)
            root = tree.getroot()
            for child in root.iter('data'):
                if child.attrib.get('namespace') == 'preserve':
                    node = child[0]
                    if node.tag == "value" and node.text != None and not node.text in definicoes:
                        definicoes.add(node.text)
    return definicoes


def escrever_arquivo(definicoes, caminho):
    if caminho.endswith(".pt.resx"):
        tree = ET.parse(caminho)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for child in root.iter('data'):
            if child.attrib.get('namespace') == 'preserve':
                node = child[0]
                if node.tag == "value" and node.text != None and node.text in definicoes:
                    node.text = definicoes[node.text]
        tree.write(caminho, encoding="UTF-8")
        anexar_cabecalho(caminho)

def existe_traducao(definicoes, caminho):
    if caminho.endswith(".resx"):
        tree = ET.parse(caminho)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for child in root.iter('data'):
            if child.attrib.get('namespace') == 'preserve':
                node = child[0]
                if node.tag == "value" and node.text != None and len(node.text) > 0 and node.text not in definicoes:
                    return False
        return True
```

Comment: I wonder why you're not using the Standard for resx localization using the usual locale specifiers... C# (and Vb.NET) deals just fine with `ResourceFile.pt_PT.resx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the possible ways to improve on following the *DRY principle* would be to extract the XML tree iteration part which is the same in all 3 functions. Something like this generator:

```
def values(tree):
    root = tree.getroot()
    for child in root.iter('data'):
        if child.attrib.get('namespace') == 'preserve':
            node = child[0]
            if node.tag == "value" and node.text is not None:
                yield node
```

Then, you can use it this way:

```
tree = ET.parse(caminho)
for node in values(tree):
    # do something with node
```